# How do i resolve checkDebugDuplicateClasses in Godot

Tags: android, debugging, admob, godot

I have been trying to implement Admob in godot for android and i have been stuck in trying to resolve debugDuplicateClasses. I have tried reinstalling the android library but nothing seems to solve the issue,i am using custom build.
Here's a screenshot

[image: Debug Screenshot]

Comment: did u solve this?

Comment: no I wasn't able to solve it.